# Success snapshot table in database. But can not CDC when have event insert,update or delete

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, debezium

I am currently using debezium connector for MySQL source to CDC data. I have successfully set up zookeeper, Kafka, Kafka connects and I have taken a successful snapshot of the entire table of the database. I have created a Kafka consumer to consume events generated in the Kafka broker. Specifically with topic hieuld.magento2.cron_schedule, I got all the messages with op of 'r'. But then I do a bunch of UPDATE, INSERT AND DELETE operations in the MySQL server and my consumer doesn't receive any 'u', 'c' or 'd' messages.

Can anyone explain to me what problem I am facing? Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You must enable binary logging for MySQL replication. The binary logs record transaction updates for replication tools to propagate changes.

> MySQL has a binary log (binlog) that records all operations in the order in which they are committed to the database. This includes changes to table schemas as well as changes to the data in tables. MySQL uses the binlog for replication and recovery.

> The Debezium MySQL connector reads the binlog, produces change events for row-level INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE operations, and emits the change events to Kafka topics. Client applications read those Kafka topics.

> As MySQL is typically set up to purge binlogs after a specified period of time, the MySQL connector performs an initial consistent snapshot of each of your databases. The MySQL connector reads the binlog from the point at which the snapshot was made.

Comment: Hey, I have exactly the same problem in SQL Server always on database. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @ozgenbaris  - I am facing the same issue with always on read only replica. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @Akshay I've solved the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70213527/10178107). Please take a look.