# Debezium not tracking CDC after successful snapshot of Always On SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, debezium

We have an Always On SQL Server instance. I want to track CDC events on some tables using Debezium. By following the official tutorials on debezium's website, I registered a connector with following properties:

```
{
    "name": "debezium-alwayson-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector",
        "database.hostname": "<ip-address>",
        "database.port": "1433",
        "database.user": "<username>",
        "database.password": "<password>",
        "database.dbname": "<db_name>",
        "database.server.name": "<server_name>",
        "table.include.list": "dbo.<table_name>",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory.alwayson",
        "tombstones.on.delete":"false",
        "transforms":"Reroute",
        "transforms.Reroute.type":"io.debezium.transforms.ByLogicalTableRouter",
        "transforms.Reroute.topic.regex":"(.*)",
        "transforms.Reroute.topic.replacement":"cdc_landing.$1",
        "database.applicationIntent": "ReadOnly"
    }
}
```

The problem here is that, debezium successfully snapshots table to the related Kafka topic but does not track cdc events after snapshot. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By following [Dude0001](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68225933/10178107)'s answer, we found out that we didn't have the privileges to execute that SQL command. For those who are having this kind of problem, please check that you have the correct privileges. **Important Note:** In debezium's [source code](https://github.com/debezium/debezium/blob/c5370c87dfdce1c20907c621ded7c2a8e96ef798/debezium-connector-sqlserver/src/main/java/io/debezium/connector/sqlserver/SqlServerConnection.java#L89) it is stated that the referenced SQL command is not being used, but since we were using version 1.7, debezium was trying to execute that command and failed.